# Python, Connectin Refused 10061

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking

I keep getting this error

> [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

I'm running Windows 7 64 bit, no virus or protection software, and python is allowed through my firewall (I've also tried turning my firewall completely off but same result). When I run the server and use telnet it connects just fine. When I try to connect to the server with the client it fails. Any suggestions as to what I could try to fix this? If you need more information just ask and I'll provide.

**Client Code**

```
import socket
import sys
def main():
   host = ""
   port = 8934
   message = "Hello World!"

   host = raw_input("Enter IP: ")
   #Create Socket
   try:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   except socket.error, msg:
      print "Failed to create socket. Error code: %s Error Message: %s"%(str(msg[0]),msg[1])
      sys.exit()
   print "Socket created"

   #Connec to Server
   print host
   print port
   s.connect((host,port))
   print "You are connected to %s with IP adress of %s"%(host,host)

   #Send Data
   try:
      s.sendall(message)
   except socket.error:
      print "Failed to send."
   #Receive Data
      reply = s.recv(4096)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

**Server Code**

```
# !usr/bin/python

import socket
import sys

HOST = ""
PORT = 8934

def main():
   #Setup socket
   try:
      s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   except socket.error,msg:
      print "Unable to create socket"
      sys.exit()
   print "Socket created."

   #Bind to adress
   try:
      s.bind((HOST,PORT))
   except socket.error,msg:
      print "Bind failed. Closing..."
      sys.exit()
   print "Socket bound."

   #Start listening
   s.listen(10)
   print "Socket Listening"

   #Accept connection
   conn, addr = s.accept()
   print "Connected to %s:%s"%(addr[0],addr[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: You realize this server will quit as soon as it accepts the first connection, right? So there's no way your code that tries to receive data from it or send to it will work, once you get past this problem?

Comment: Also, please fix your indentation, so we can copy and paste your code to run it, or just read it, without having to guess.

Comment: @abarnert I realize it will quit yes. All I'm worried about is getting it to connect at all then I will work from there. Sorry about the indention, I didn't realize it goofed it up.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the fact that the server quits is the only actual problem here. You can only run the client one time, then the server quits, and if you run the client again, you get a 10061 error (or, on Unix, a 61 error). If you run another server, you can run one client again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a guess at your indentation, and running your code… it works just fine.* (As long as I type in `127.0.0.1` when it asks me for the IP.)

Of course the second time I run the client (if I haven't restarted the server) I get a connection-refused error. But that's just because you've coded a server that immediately quits as soon as it gets the first connection. So the second time you run the client, there is no server, so the OS rejects the connection.

You can always run the server again, which lets you run the client one more time. (Except that the server may get a 10048 error when it tries to bind the socket, because the OS is keeping it around for the previous owner. If you see that, look at `SO_REUSEADDR` in the docs.)

* By "works just fine" I mean that it connects, and prints out the following before quitting:

```
Socket created
127.0.0.1
8934
You are connected to 127.0.0.1 with IP adress of 127.0.0.1
```

Obviously it never sends anything to the server or receives anything back, because the server has no `send` or `recv` calls, or anything else.

Comment: Alright, I was making a stupid mistake. I was trying to connect through the wrong IP. Wow I feel dumb now. Thanks for insight abarnet!